# Which British accent is closest to the standard Australian accent?

Tags: history, dialects, accent

Which British accent is closest to the general Australian accent?

Does this correlate with where the majority of British Australians originate?

Any comments on the variations of either accents by regions are welcome.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question about accents. Seriously off-topic. Plus, what the hell is the "standard Australian accent"?. G'day sport, let's have a tinny and a lamington in the dunny, you galah?

Comment: If I said standard American accent, would you know what I meant?

Comment: The reason I phrased it this way is because there is not as much variation in the Aussie accent as there is in the UK accent. This is also why I added the last sentence. I'm in the English stack exchange.. What other stack exchange community would be more applicable?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you be more specific? Provide details about the accents you're talking about. Also show the research you've done.

Comment: Generally, when people use the phrase "standard accent" (in America at least), they use a newscaster as an example. Newscasters are trained to speak in a standard accent. I would be very surprised if this wasn't true in Australia as well.

Comment: @alrob [“General American doesn’t exist. He was demoted to private or sergeant a long, long time ago.”](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/is-there-a-place-in-america-where-people-speak-without-accents)

Comment: @tchrist Wasn't he promoted again with a slight name change so that he became Captain America? He's been slinging that shield around ever since.

Comment: @tchrist https://www.washingtoncitypaper.com/columns/straight-dope/article/13047690/why-do-newscasters-all-talk-the-same-what-would-happen

Comment: @alrob I'll take the strength of my reference over yours, thank you very much. :)

Comment: There isn't a general Australian accent. It's true we don't have as many variations as England does, but still we do have variations, more then one of which are common enough that I don't think it is possible to pick just one as *the* accent. What do you mean by "British Australian"? I would have thought that meant somebody who was born in Britain and then moved here, and they usually speak with their original British accent.

Comment: Did you do any research? I'm sure there must me some information on the 'Net about this. Didn't the Aussie accent originate from the drunkenness of the deportees from the UK to Botany Bay? [link](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/australia/11957994/Gday-mate-Lazy-Australian-accent-caused-by-alcoholic-slur-of-heavy-drinking-early-settlers.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is some variation in the Australian accent, and there are many sources for some of the words assumed to be Australian. The main influence is usually believed to be the various London accents. Australian rhyming slang is Cockney rhyming slang (again from part of London).

Comment: I have upvoted this in error. se my answer below.

Comment: I don't see any connection between British rhyming slang and the Aussie accent.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is a play/ply shift /pleɪ/ > /plʌɪ/ in various vowel sounds that is common to Cockney/Estuary English and standard Australian English, this is somewhat misleading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_English

> Australian English began to diverge from British English after the First Settlers, who set up the Colony of New South Wales, arrived in 1788. By 1820, their speech was recognised as being different from British English. Australian English arose from the intermingling of early settlers, who were from a great variety of mutually intelligible dialectal regions of Great Britain and Ireland, and quickly developed into a distinct variety of English which differs considerably from most other varieties of English in vocabulary, accent, pronunciation, register, grammar and spelling.

Comment: Why not come straight to the point and say that the deportees from Britain to Botany Bay were low-class poorly spoken criminals, and when they arrived in Oz they got so drunk that their pronunciation become an alcoholic drawl resulting in the so-called 'Strine' accent that we know today.

Comment: Mainly because the oversimplification is oversimplified.

Comment: Not according to my relatives in Oz!

Comment: I have precedence: I'm from the country that sent them there...